# How bind list of objects from Multipart param to objectMapper?

Tags: java, spring, rest, jackson

My api receives a param MultipartFile. I am unable to bind that file with a list of objects?

I work on `Spring-boot 2.0.8` with `Java 8`

I tried this:

```
public ResponseEntity<Long> addReferenceByFile(HttpServletRequest request,
                                               @PathVariable String numeroLicence,                                                     
@RequestParam("references") MultipartFile references) throws URISyntaxException {
```

and this:

```
try {
     InputStream inputStream = references.getInputStream();
     ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
     ArrayList<Reference> references1 = objectMapper.readValues(references, Reference.class);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

ObjectMapper doesn't accept `InputStream` data. My requirement is to get a list to use for unitary treatment.

Would someone help me find a solution for this issue?

Comment: Hope this will be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30043173/2987755

Comment: I understand but no, I don' want my customer send the file, and the content file in two parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`InputStreamReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) to read the multipart `InputStream`:

```
try (InputStream in = references.getInputStream()) {
    objectMapper.readValue(new InputStreamReader(in), Reference.class);
}
```

Comment: It's missing something no? in which and type of variable I get the result?

Comment: You need to assign `readValue()` method return to something. You haven't shown what is your payload and expected result type so there is no way to guess.

Comment: Yes I know, I want to have : ArrayList<Reference>

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    try {
        TypeFactory typeFactory = objectMapper.getTypeFactory();
        CollectionType collectionType = typeFactory.constructCollectionType(
            List.class, Reference.class);
        List<Reference> referenceList = objectMapper.readValue(references.getInputStream(), collectionType);



    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new CustomException(CustomError.ERROR_REFERENCE_FILE_BAD_FORMAT);
    }
```