# Is it any ability to upload MultipartFile with Model in Swagger? (In comment 415 Unsupported Media Type Resolved)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I'm using the last (and only)

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

with spring boot

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>
```

I would like to have ability to upload file and model in one controller, so I created one:
[image]

in this case on swagger-ui I see only file uploading without model:
[image]

I tried this case in postman and it works fine
[image]

Is it a bug? Or should I add some other annotations to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was in Configuration class, in Docket Bean.
Here I'm defining route to my Controllers to exclude others from swagger-ui.
The problem was in DocumentationType, OpenApi3.0 is maintaining multitype files uploading, and Swagger2 don't.

[image]

Next problem which I faced was:

> ***415 Unsupported Media Type***

Resolution:

**First way:**
If you will use postman/javaScript framework -> you have to define media-type of every RequestPart (actually don't need for file, for file it will be set automatically).
example in POSTMAN:
[image]

**Second way:** is implement maintaining of octet-stream, because spring set it by default in `AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.class` if there is no content-type header in request part.
(I'm using  `spring-boot-starter-parent 2.4.1 -> spring-webmvc 5.3.2`)
[image: Y]

**So here is 2 cases I found (to map response JSON to DTO):**

**1 case** (not recommended):
Set supporting to JSON converter:
[image]

**2 case:**
Define new Converter class which will work definitely for needed classes (in my case it is `MDVersionDTO.class`) and definitely when it comes like ***octet-stream***, to implement it, ovveride `canRead()` method.
[image]

---

### UPDATE FOR SPRING-BOOT 2.7.0

Faced again, and now DocumaentationType.OAS_30 not working...
So, to resolve:

1. I implemented same MultipartJSONConverter and made it *@Component*
2. I used *DocumaentationType.SWAGGER_2*
3. Removed @RequestBody annotation and used like this:
   [image]

In this case you will have ability to upload files with request Body, but you will not have model example in swagger, it will be empty.
[image]

Comment: Faced again same on spring-boot 2.7.0