# How to define a controller method as to accept a JSON that have a media type filed with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, media-type

I'm trying to take a Json object from front-end. This represent a course. The course have a field logo, the image of the course. In my Controller I have the following method:

```
@PostMapping(value="/register-course", consumes = "multipart/form-data" )
    public Response courseCreated(@RequestBody @Valid CourseCreatedRequest courseCreatedRequest, @RequestPart(value = "logo") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        return Response.ok().setPayload(registerCours(courseCreatedRequest, file));
    }

        private CourseDto registerCours(CourseCreatedRequest courseCreatedRequest, MultipartFile file) throws
        IOException {
            CourseDto courseDto = new CourseDto()
                    .setCourseName(courseCreatedRequest.getCourseName())
                    .setCourseDescription(courseCreatedRequest.getCourseDescription())
                    .setCoursePrice(courseCreatedRequest.getCoursePrice())
                    .setIsCourseActive(courseCreatedRequest.getIsCourseActive())
                    .setIsCourseFree(courseCreatedRequest.getIsCourseFree())
                    .setLogo(file.getBytes());

            return courseService.createNewCourse(courseDto);
        }
```

In the Service layer I have the logic to compress(when persisiting the image in DB) and uncomress (when render the image back to fend):

```
@PrePersist
public CourseDto createNewCourse(CourseDto newCourseDto) {

    Courses course = courseRepositoryDao.findByCourseName(newCourseDto.getCourseName());
    if (course == null) {

        course = new Courses()
                .setCourseName(newCourseDto.getCourseName())
                .setCourseDescription(newCourseDto.getCourseDescription())
                .setCoursePrice(newCourseDto.getCoursePrice())
                .setIsCourseFree(newCourseDto.getIsCourseFree())
                .setIsCourseActive(newCourseDto.getIsCourseActive())
                .setLogo(compressZLib(newCourseDto.getLogo()))
        ;
        return CourseMapper.toUserDtoFreeCourses(courseRepositoryDao.save(course));
    }
    throw exception(EntityType.NEWCOURSE, ExceptionType.DUPLICATE_ENTITY, newCourseDto.getCourseName());
}
```

When I send the JSON with the logo field as an image file via POSTMAN, I get 415 Error - Unsuported media type.

Where I am wrong? I think that I need to change my controller, but how?
I need somehow to take the image from the JSON with MultipartFile class?

Update:
I sent JSON and a file in body, and I think this is the problem. I need to put MultipartFile in controller.

I have followe other answers and still 415 error. In postman I left Content-Type with no value.

Comment: annotating the courseCreatedRequest argument with @RequestBody is enough to bind the JSON data sent from the clients.

Comment: yes, but I sent JSON and file in body, and I think this is the problem. I need to put MultipartFile in controller.

Comment: Please check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54575893/spring-boot-multipart-unsupported-media-type

Comment: Can you show us the front end code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot - Multipart - Unsupported Media Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54575893/spring-boot-multipart-unsupported-media-type)

Comment: @ Dread Pirate Alex ,I dont't have a f end. I tested with Postman.

Comment: Did you add "consumes = "multipart/form-data" in the controller?. Also check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52818107/how-to-send-the-multipart-file-and-json-data-to-spring-boot

Comment: @Dread Pirate Alex, I added and still 415 error.

Comment: @Triet Doan , yes it helps. It was a part of the answer. Tks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me how I did something similar was like so:
In the back end (Spring):

```
@PostMapping(path = "/{your-route-goes-here}", consumes = "multipart/form-data")
public Course addCourse(@RequestPart(required = false, name = "file") MultipartFile file,  @RequestPart("course") Course course) {

    // do stuff here
}
```

In the front end javascript (with axios for the http request):

```
   const course = {
      "property": "value"
   }

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("file", file);
  formData.append("course", course);
  
  axios
    .post("/your-route-goes-here", formData)

  // etc
```

Please check out the pictures for reference:

backend:
[image]

postman:
[image]

the 'Course' model:

[image]

Comment: can you send screenshots of postman? the body and the headers... Also does the CourseCreatedRequest have a default constructor??

Comment: It works like u said but with a minor difference. I have put in CONTENT TYPE column multipart/form-data to the file row. And it work like this. Tks!

Comment: :)) Good luck with your project 

Comment: Tks bro! Keep in touch!