# Send MultipartFile file in request body with other data in postman

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, postman

I have a post method that accepts the following Dto class,

public class MyDto1 {

```
private MultipartFile f1;
private MultipartFile f2;
private MultipartFile f3;
private List < MyDto2 > filesList;
private String description;
```

}

public class MyDto2 {

```
private Long id,
private String description;
private MultipartFile f1;
private MultipartFile f2;
private MultipartFile f3;
```

}

How can I set the request body in postman to send this request, I tried setting all multipart variables as `null` and it works. But now I want to test with MultipartFile, how can I add MultipartFile with the body

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52818107/how-to-send-the-multipart-file-and-json-data-to-spring-boot

Comment: I am using ``MyDto1`` as @RequestBody, and my object structure is a bit complex, is it possible to use the above method for this as well

Comment: specially can I pass MyDto2 list with the request body?